# jQuery hover event over iframe/flash in IE6-9 not working?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, iframe, z-index

See the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/sPvYk/3/

For the purpose of this demo the close button is visible, but in real life it's hidden out of view until you hover over the upper right corner. So pretend it is not there.

Move your cursor to the upper right corner of the youtube embed (not over the button), in safari and firefox this will cause the button to move/animate downwards into view.

However, in IE nothing happens.

I have made sure that the z-index of the menu panel is higher than the z-index of the div that contains the iframe.

Is this something that can be fixed?

Comment: Having this exact same problem! Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Also, I've added a variable to the youtube URL, `wmode=transparent`. This means that the thing does drop down in front now, but unfortunately IE still doesn't pick up on you hovering! http://jsfiddle.net/sPvYk/3/